# Masking last 4 digits in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here I am using regex pattern to mask last 4 digits for Credit Card number.

```
$("#ccnumber").html(ccnbr); //ccnumber refers to div ID

$("#ccnumber").text(function(_, val) {
  return val.replace(/\d{12}(\d{4})/, "************$1");
});
```

It is applicable for only 16 digit credit card numbers. But, I need to mask the incoming numbers (may be 10 or 11) by `*` and show the last 4 digits.

Is it possible in javascript/jQuery?

```js
$('#ccnumber').text(function(_, val) {
  return val.replace(/\d{12}(\d{4})/, "************$1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ccnumber">1234567891234567</div>
```

Comment: Assuming you are doing this in the browser (and your mention of jQuery implies this), this is very close to pointless in terms of security. You should do this server side.

Comment: Ya I know. this is very bad practise in client side. But for displaying purpose, I need to do like this..No other way..

Comment: Also note that matching the number of asterisks to the number of digits in the card is a form of information leakage. There's a reason we stopped doing this for passwords 20 years ago.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");
```

to mask all but last 4 digits in a given number of more than 4 digits.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL4vY1/1)

**Explanation:**

- This reges uses a positive lookahead `(?=\d{4})` which means match should be followed by 4 digits.
- `\d` matches a single digit with above lookahead condition and replaces that by `*`

Comment: This regex only masks the number, if there any string how can I hide them also?

Comment: Use `.replace(/\w(?=\w{4})/g, "*");`

Comment: `.replace(/\S(?=\S{4})/g, "*");` will match with any alphanumeric string

Comment: @Shrutee: `\S` matches non-whitespace character not just alphanumeric. For matching `alphanumeric` use `[\da-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 6):

The Function will mask first 12 digits of card number as displayed below :-

> Input : 4444444444444444
>
> Output : **** **** **** 4444

```js
function formatCardNumber(event, element) {
 if (isNaN(event.key) && !isAllowedKey(event)) {
  event.preventDefault();
 } else {
  if (event.keyCode != 8) {
   if(element.value.length > 14) {
    var position = element.selectionStart;
    element.value = element.value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/^(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3 $4");
    if(element.value.length != 19) {
     element.setSelectionRange(position, position);
    }
   }
   else {
    element.value = element.value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ');
   }
  }
 }  
}

function isAllowedKey(event) {
 var allowed = false;
 if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39) {
  allowed = true;
 }
 return allowed;
}

function limit(event, element, max_chars) {
 if(isTextSelected(element)){                  //
  max_chars += 1;
 }
 if (element.value.length >= max_chars && !isAllowedKey(event)) {
  event.preventDefault();
 }
}

function showCardValue() {
 document.getElementById("cardNo").value = document.getElementById("cardNoSafe").value;
}

function isTextSelected(input) {
 var startPosition = input.selectionStart;
 var endPosition = input.selectionEnd;

 var selObj = document.getSelection();
 var selectedText = selObj.toString();

 if (selectedText.length != 0) {
  input.focus();
  input.setSelectionRange(startPosition, endPosition);
  return true;
 } else if (input.value.substring(startPosition, endPosition).length != 0) {
  input.focus();
  input.setSelectionRange(startPosition, endPosition);
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function hideCardValue(val) {
 document.getElementById("cardNoSafe").value = val;
 var len = val.length;
 if (len >= 14) {
  const regex = /\d{4}(?= \d{1})/g;
  const substr = "****";
  document.getElementById("cardNo").value = val.replace(regex, substr);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <input name="AccountNo" id="cardNo" placeholder="Card Number" title="Card Number" class="form-control" onfocus="showCardValue()" onblur="hideCardValue(this.value)" onkeypress="formatCardNumber(event, this); limit(event, this, 19) " onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" tabindex="2" autocomplete="nope" type="text">
<span class="placeholder-text" style="display: none;">Please enter Card Number</span>
<input name="cardNoSafe" id="cardNoSafe" value="" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rajnish, your answer helped me to get over same kind of masking I had to do for one my my web application.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Javascript approach without the use of RegEx:

Check [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/kpymasr5/2)

```
var mainStr = '1234567891234567',
    vis = mainStr.slice(-4),
    countNum = '';

for(var i = (mainStr.length)-4; i>0; i--){
    countNum += '*';
}

alert(countNum+vis);
```

Answer (score 3):

If somebody has a card placeholder through space, like "4242 4242 4242 4242", then you have to use other regular expression: \d{4}(?= \d{4}) and replace on "****":

Full example:

```
str = str.replace(/\d{4}(?= \d{4})/g, "****");
```

It will replace card "4242 4242 4242 4242" as "**** **** **** 4242"

## [Test example](https://regex101.com/r/uB2cM4/2)

Answer (score 2):

```
 var input = "1234567890";
 input = input.replace(/^(\d{0,4})(\d{0,3})/, '$1 $2')
 var prefix = input.substr(0, input.length - 4);
 var suffix = input.substr(-4);
 var masked = prefix.replace(/\d/g, '*');
 var a = masked + suffix;
 console.log(a)
```

```
Console Output: 
**** **7890
```

Comment: Can you explain

Comment: Basically what I am doing here is we are using regex expression and replace function to mask the input string with spaces. Later prefix and suffix are the substring of first 6 characters and last 4 characters. Then I am replacing the prefix with * character and concatenating the output string.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can simply use padStart() or padEnd() to mask the beginning or the end of a string:

```
var str = "This is my sentence";
var strMaskedStart = str.slice(-4).padStart(str.length, '*');
var strMaskedEnd = str.substr(0, str.length - 4).padEnd(str.length, '*');

console.log(strMaskedStart); // Output: ***************ence
console.log(strMaskedEnd); // Output: This is my sent****
```

If you want to read more about it, then look at the MDN Web Docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is perfect for digits only but I came across a scenario where the input can be any string (credit card numbers, phone numbers, secret questions etc) and if we want to achieve the same on that (i.e. masking all characters except the last 4) then you can use the following:

```
str.replace(/.(?=\d{4})/g, "#")
```

My requirement was to replace it with # sign. The point is to use `.`, which is for any single character check. The explanation of accepted answer still holds, this just works for any characters and not only digits. Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. But remember this is very, **very** bad practice.

```
$('#ccnumber').text(function(_,val) {

   return val.replace(/(\d*?)(\d{4})/, "************$1");
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I am asking for n number of options...not for just 10 or 12

Answer (score 0):

> This is a pure javascript answer.

```
function cardHide(input) {
  //use slice to remove first 12 elements
  let first12 = input.slice(0, 12);
  //define what char to use to replace numbers
  let char = '*'
  let repeatedChar = char.repeat(input.length -4);
  // replace numbers with repeated char
  first12 = first12.replace(first12, repeatedChar);
  //concat hidden char with last 4 digits of input
  let hiddenNumbers = first12 + input.slice(input.length-4);
  

  //return
  return hiddenNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
let res =str.slice(0, -4) + "****";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
MOBILE NO : <p id="demo">8819922301</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the code for removing last 4 characters and adding 4 stars instead of it.