# Java Regex to mask alphanumeric string and show last 4 digits

Tags: java, regex, string, masking

I have an input string that looks like any of the following:

- Z43524429
- 46D92S429
- 3488DFJ33

Basically the string can contain alphabet characters or digits. However it cannot contain symbols, just letters and numbers. I would like to mask it so that it looks like this:

- *****4429
- *****S429
- *****FJ33

I've looked everywhere to find an java code example that uses regex to mask this. I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545202/masking-last-4-digits-in-javascript) on stack but that assumes that the input is purely a number.

I adjusted the regex to `/\w(?=\w{4})/g` to include characters as well. It seems to work [here](https://regex101.com/r/jO9aU1/1). But when I try to implement it in java it doesn't work. Here's the line in my java code:

```
String mask = accountNumber.replace("\\w(?=\\w{4})", "*");
```

The mask ends up being the same as the accountNumber. So obviously the regex is not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `replaceAll` for regex

Comment: If the string has always the same format, you don't need a regex. Build a new string that starts with five `*` and ends with the four last characters of the original string.

Comment: Thanks for the question BTW. Because of that I found Regex for String masking. Very Helpful..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), which doesn't use regular expressions.

Try [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

Use **replaceAll** over **replace**

```java
String mask = accountNumber.replaceAll("\\w(?=\\w{4})", "*");
```