# The value of textbox changing automatically to asterisk (****)

Tags: asp.net, web, textbox, telerik

I've a textbox to capture card no. But this value '6222040000030002', the textbox value is render as '**********' automatically.
The textbox textmode is set as SingleLine only.
I can't figure it out why this behavior is happening. 
Any suggestion.

Below the html for rad textBox.

```
 <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txt_receiver_accno" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Label="*Account No." AutoPostBackValidates="true"
                                    LabelCssClass="RemitTitle" Width="254px" Style="text-transform: uppercase;" MaxLength="60">
                                    <ClientEvents OnBlur="checkBankFormatClient" />
                                </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

[Plain Textbox][2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/bog3U.png

Grid [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzRr7.png

Comment: Check the type of the box. Or adding code will be more helpful

Comment: @Shahzeb I just edited and added the html. It's just simple textbox.

Comment: What does `checkBankFormatClient` do?

Comment: @VDWWD checkBankFormatClient () is checking the value for the textbox using few regular expressions.

Comment: @sthashakun can you add the textmode explicitly as I can't see the `textmode` property in the given code.

Comment: Is that happening also on tab out (blur) or key up?

Comment: @Shahzeb I did add the textmode property, still same. The weird part is it happening for few number only. for e.g. 6222040000030002

Comment: @ArunVinoth it happening after the post back happens. The value stored in table is numeric only but the UI the number is changing to ******.

Comment: See if something implemented like this in Js library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545202/masking-last-4-digits-in-javascript

Comment: @ArunVinoth sadly there non masking js used. Surprisingly this behavior is happening for few numbers only not for all.

Comment: What are those spl numbers? Are they matching this: https://regular-expressions.mobi/creditcard.html?wlr=1..... Also try to add new control (without any fancy) or remove other properties in existing control like causesvaliation, onblur, etc one by one & isolate the root cause

Comment: @ArunVinoth even when I used the plain html textbox with that value, the result are same. This the number 6222040000030002.
Also, the same thing is happening in gridview  also.
Refer to image 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if their is any firewall level security added for credit card number on the server.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. It fact the issue was caused due to security masking done in WAF ( windows application firewall) itself. That number matched the format of valid union pay card. Tqvm for  your suggestion.